# Work done by gravitational field and and proof of gravity being conservative force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy, conservative-field

We know gravitational force is a conservative force. So work done by the field in moving an object form one position to other and again moving it bact to the initial position should be zero. But while studying about the work done by the field I wanted to see whether it is true or not but obtained that W1+W2≠0.

It would be much helpful if someone points out my mistake (about the concept or any mathematical error)and help me to learn more about this topic.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just forget about the integrant and check what you get if you swap the integration limits.

Comment: But the angle between force and displacement is changing in both the cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard doubt. Similar problem one can encounter in the Coulomb force (as both have similar form).
The whole problem is in the limits of the integration.
Consider a function $y=x^2$
[image]

The $\int_1^2ydx$ means that $x$ varies from 1 to 2 infinitesimally, and in the process we are summing $f(x)dx$. So the limit in the integral gives us itself a sense of direction in which the change in x takes place.
$\int_2^1ydx$ shows that x varies from 2 to 1. So, vectorially there is no need to write $-dx$ in the expression $\int_2^1ydx$

Now coming back to the original question.
**Case [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1r9N8.png) When the particle move from P to Q**
If the particle moves from the $P$ to $Q$.
Gravitational force= $-\frac{GMm}{r^2}\hat r$ and displacement = $dr\hat r$
Work done = $F.dx=\int_{r_a}^{r_b}-\frac{GMm}{r^2}\hat r.dr\hat r$
$\implies W= GMm\Big[\frac{1}{r}\Big]_{r_a}^{r_b}$
So, $W_{P\to Q}=GMm\Big[\frac{1}{r_b}-\frac{1}{r_a}\Big]$
So, work done by gravity is negative which is in accordance with our intuition.

**Case[2] When the particle move from Q to P**
Gravitational force= $-\frac{GMm}{r^2}\hat r$ and displacement = $dr\hat r$
Here there is no need to write displacement = $-dr\hat r$ as we give the direction of displacement in the limits of integral.
So, work done by gravity, $W=\int_{r_b}^{r_a}-\frac{GMm}{r^2}\hat r.dr\hat r$
$W=-GMm\Big[-\frac{1}{r}\Big]_{r_b}^{r_a}$
$W_{Q\to P}=-GMm\Big[\frac{1}{r_b}-\frac{1}{r_a}\Big]$
So, work done by gravity from Q to P is positive which is in accordance to our intuition
Thus, $W_{P\to Q}+W_{Q\to P}=0$

So, we can see that the whole problem lies in the wrong interpretation of the limits when we vary our domain from the reverse side (not in the usual increasing fashion). The limits of the integration itself gives the direction of the displacement so there is no need to add another - sign in the expression of displacement.

Comment: Please, do not answer homework-like and/or check-my-work questions. This only motivates more of those questions.

Comment: No, I don't think that is a homework like question, Here OP is confused with the direction of displacement and the limit in which we integrate the function. He has shown his work also.

Comment: Thanks a lot @iti....... I had misconception about the limits of integration that is why I was so confused about gravitational field.......  Thanks again you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit tricky and it has to do with absolute values of differentials.

When you use the scalar product $$\vec{F}\cdot\vec{ds}=|F||ds|\cos(\theta)$$ you "loose" information on the sign of $ds=|\vec{ds}|$ which is now contained in the cosine. In other words, when you go from $b$ to $a$, you are actually doing the integral

$$\int_{r_a}^{r_b} \vec{F}\cdot\vec{ds} = \int_{r_a}^{r_b}|F||ds|\cos(\theta)=-\int_{r_b}^{r_a} {GMm\over r^2} |ds|$$
where I could set
$$|F|={GMm\over r^2}$$ because it's positive but we are left with this weird $|ds|$. Because you are doing the integral "from right to left" you are implictly assuming that $ds<0$ and so, because you have an absolute value, you need to add a minus sign $|ds|=-ds$.
So your integral actually is

$$-\int_{r_b}^{r_a} {GMm\over r^2} |ds|=+\int_{r_b}^{r_a} {GMm\over r^2} ds$$ and you recover the sign that allows you to sum $W_1+W_2=0$.

The point is then that $$|ds|_{a\rightarrow b}=ds$$ but $$|ds|_{b\rightarrow a}=-ds$$ where the subscripts refer to the direction of the integral.

Let me add a bit on why this happens. You know that

$$\int_b^a f(x) dx  = -\int_a^b f(x)dx$$

because $f(x)$ did not change and the integral is a "sum" (i.e. if I sum the element from $a$ to $b$ or from $b$ to $a$ it should not change..), this rule somehow implies that when you go from $b$ to $a$ your $dx$ becomes negative. This is because $dx$ is an "infinitesimal path-element" and you are now going on the path but in *opposite* sense, $dx$ will change sign and you need to take care of that when using absolute values.

The direction of the integral is somewhat already included in $dx$ because of the way integral are defined, so you don't need to include the explicit $\cos(\theta)$ term when using the scalar product, becuase $dx$ is already directional if you include the integration limits (or rather: you need to take care of the direction you are going twice, once including the $\cos(\theta)$ term *and* once including the fact that $ds$ (now inside the absolute value $|ds|$) is now negative, and thus getting $-- = +$).

Comment: Thanks a lot @JalfredP...... I had misconception about the limits of integration that is why I was so confused about gravitational field.......  Thanks again you helped me a lot.

Comment: I think it is a common problem - in general always imagine work as $F\cos(\theta)ds$ there $ds$ is an unsigned displacement :)

Comment: To be honest I faced this problem a year ago and was searching for a solution from then......  The problem basically arose due to not having enough idea about the relation between integration,limits and physics. Now i understand that in this case we have to consider the absolute value of the $\cos(\theta)$ ignoring the sign and the rest of the work is done by the limits.

Comment: Or keep the cosine (sometimes more clear) and add a minus sign. One approach or the other my be better depending on the functional form of the force and of the path you are integrating.